# Transfer MS SQL Server data to Oracle tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, types, long-integer

I am transferring table data from SQL Server to Oracle with the use of a database link. Although my connection and some transfers run smoothly some of them give me the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
```

My query is like this:

`insert into FCPEERANALYSISPROPS  select * from FCPEERANALYSISPROPS@mssql;`

As I tried to see to which column it fails (run the query to each column of the table separately) I figured out that the problem is raising for one column which in SQL Server is defined as `nvarchar(4000)` and in oracle is defined as: `VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)`.

Can you please advise on this issue?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10405_01/doc/appdev.120/e10379/ss_oracle_compared.htm Here you can find a table of datatypes mapping between Oracle and SQL Server. It says that `NVARCHAR(n)` should be mapped to `VARCHAR(n*2)`

Comment: @NenadZivkovic you mean that I have to declare a `VARCHAR2(8000)`?

Answer (score 0):

from [this](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html) you can see that `VARCHAR2` is `bytes`, while `nvarchar` is for unicode (2 bytes or more) hence you need to

- duplicate table structure in Oracle with NVARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR2
- then run the `insert into ... select ... from`

Comment: `varchar2` and `nvarchar2` can both hold multi-byte characters; `varchar2` is defined [either by number of bytes or number of characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i54330). There's more in [the concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#autoId10).

Comment: I get the same error. Here's what I do: `alter table <table_name> modify (<column_name> nvarchar2(2000));`

Comment: from the link above I see that the max size of `nvarchar2` and `varchar2` are **4000** bytes you are starting from a nvarchar(4000) which is **8000** bytes. so it seems that you need to split the column in 2 of **2000** and do `left(YourColumn,2000)` to the first and `substring(YourColunmn, 2001, 2000)` to the second. The next issue will be that you'll need to duplicate the functionality for your `CRUD`, for `SELECT`, and `DELETE` a `view` will suffice, for `UPDATE` and `INSERT` you'll need to work harder